# Validating linux directory but need to omit leading and trailing slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to make a regex pattern to validate directory structure on linux. I used the following regex to validate it:

`^/|(/[\w-]+)+$`

I need to satisfy the following rules:

```
/                  False as we dont need leading slash
/AB_D/ef-123/sub/  False we dont need trailing slash 
AB_D/ef-123/sub    true
a//b               False as slashes are consecutive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/PnTg0S/2):

```
^[^\/](?:[\w-\/]?[^\/])*[^\/]?$
```

1. Firstly, it matches strings that their first and last characters **aren't** slashes.
2. Then `(?:[\w-\/]?[^\/])` matches strings of length 1 or 2, that consist of one of the following:

- A slash, followed by a non-slash
- Two consecutive non-slash characters
- A non-slash

Please note that I wasn't fully aware of all the valid/invalid characters, but you can just replace `[^\/]` with the expression that represents the valid ones.